# Existence of a faithful irreducible representation using Möbius function

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, lattices, enumerative-combinatorics

Let $G$ be a finite group, $L(G)$ its subgroup lattice and $\mu$ the Möbius function.
Consider the Euler totient of $G$ defined as follows:
$$ \varphi(G) = \sum_{H \le G}\mu(H,G) |H| $$
Let $X=\{M_1, \dots, M_n \}$ be the set of maximal subgroups of $G$. By applying the *Crosscut Theorem* with $X$ (see [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264107/a-boolean-representation-of-the-m%C3%B6bius-function-on-a-finite-lattice#comment651597_264107) of Richard Stanley) and next the [inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), we get that:
$$ \varphi(G) = |G \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^n M_i| $$ In other words, $\varphi(G)$ is the number of elements $g \in G$ such that $\langle g \rangle = G$. It follows that 
$$ \varphi(G) \neq 0 \Leftrightarrow G \text{ cyclic}$$

Note that $\varphi(\mathbb{Z}/n) = \varphi(n)$ the usual [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function).

Now, consider the dual Euler totient of $G$ defined as follows: 
$$ \hat{\varphi}(G) = \sum_{H \le G}\mu(1,H) |G:H| $$

**Question**: $ \hat{\varphi}(G) \neq 0 \Leftrightarrow G$ has a faithful irreducible complex representation?

*Remark*: We will see below that $(\Rightarrow)$ is true. So the question reduces to $(\Leftarrow)$.
It is true for the finite simple group $G$ of order $<10000$:

$$ \begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
G & |G| & \hat{\varphi}(G) \newline 
 \hline  
  A_5 & 60     &  8   &  \newline 
 \hline
  PSL(2,7) & 168    &  228    &  \newline 
 \hline
  A_6 & 360     &   8748   &  \newline 
 \hline
  PSL(2,8) & 504     &   19056   &  \newline 
 \hline
PSL(2,11) & 660     &  24932    &  \newline 
 \hline
PSL(2,13) & 1092     &  105684    &  \newline 
 \hline
  PSL(2,17) & 2448     &   389496  &  \newline 
 \hline
  A_7 & 2520     &  188136    &  \newline 
 \hline
  PSL(2,19)& 3420     &   1148028   &  \newline 
 \hline
  PSL(2,16)& 4080     &  1935584    &  \newline 
 \hline
  PSL(3,3)& 5616      &  395496    &  \newline
 \hline
   PSU(3,3)& 6048     &  507168    &  \newline
 \hline
  PSL(2,23)& 6072     &  2234784    &  \newline
 \hline
   PSL(2,25)& 7800    &  5391800    &  \newline
 \hline
   M_{11} & 7920         &   1044192   &  \newline
 \hline
  PSL(2,27)& 9828          &   7778916   &  \newline
\end{array}$$

Any idea about the meaning of these numbers?

---

*Proof of $(\Rightarrow)$*

Consider the relative version $$ \hat{\varphi}(H,G) = \sum_{K \in [H,G]}\mu(H,K) |G:K|.$$ *Warning*: $-\hat{\varphi}(H,G)$ is **not** the Möbius invariant of the bounded coset poset $\hat{C}(H,G)$ because $$-\mu(\hat{C}(H,G)) = \sum_{K \in [H,G]}\mu(K,G) |G:K| $$ and $\mu(K,G) \neq \mu(H,K)$ in general.

Now if $[H,G]$ is boolean of rank $n$ then $\mu(K,G) = (-1)^n \mu(H,K)$; moreover (independently) by Theorem 3.21 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.06765.pdf), if $ \hat{\varphi}(H,G) \neq 0$ then there is an irreducible complex representation $V$ of $G$ such that $G_{(V^H)} = H$. Next, using a dual reformulation of the Crosscut Theorem with $X$ the set of atoms, we can extend the proof of Theorem 3.21 to any interval $[H,G]$ (i.e. without assuming it to be boolean). Finally by taking $H = 1$, we get that for any finite group $G$, if $\hat{\varphi}(G) \neq 0$ then there is an irreducible complex representation $V$ such that $G_{(V)} = 1$, which means that $V$ is faithful.

Comment: You might look at  Pálfy, P. P. On faithful irreducible representations of finite groups. Studia Sci. Math. Hungar. 14 (1979), no. 1-3, 95–98 (1982). Mathscinet says he uses the mobius function of the lattice of normal subgroups. I don't have access.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the modular maximal-cyclic group [$M_4(2)$](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/1/M4(2).html), of order $16$, has a **f**aithful **i**rreducible **c**omplex **r**epresentation (f.i.c.r.) of dimension $2$, whereas $\hat{\varphi}(M_4(2)) = 0$.

Let $B$ be the subgroup generated by the minimal subgroups of $G$. By the Crosscut Theorem, if $H  \in [1,G] \setminus [1,B]$ then $\mu(1,H) = 0$. Then $$\hat{\varphi}(G) = |G:B|  \hat{\varphi}(B)$$ So that $\hat{\varphi}(G) \neq 0 $ if and only if $\hat{\varphi}(B) \neq 0$. But we can't expect that the existence of a f.i.c.r. for $G$ implies the existence of a f.i.c.r. for $B$ (whereas the converse is true).
 In fact, $G = M_2(4)$ has a f.i.c.r. but not its $B = C_2^2$

*Improved question*:  Is $(\Leftarrow)$ true if $B=G$?
[note that $B$ is normal (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2200591/84284)), so $B=G$ for $G$ simple]

*Answer:* No, there are exactly two counter-examples of order $\le 100$: [$D_8 \rtimes C_2^2$](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/61/D8sC2%5E2.html) and [$D_8 \rtimes S_3$](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/73/D8sS3.html). They are of order $64$ and $96$ resp., and both check $B=G$, $\hat{\varphi}(G)=0$ and have a f.i.c.r. of dimension $4$.

We can still specialized the question to $G$ simple.

---

For answering the comment of Benjamin Steinberg, we will prove an alternative result involving the normal subgroup lattice, and giving a formula shorter than in Pálfy's paper (available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2P_JgZe-Zd0OG5LNnlrRG90Umc/view?usp=sharing)).

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\mathcal{N}(G)$ its normal subgroup lattice. Let $\mu_{\mathcal{N}}$ be the Möbius function for $\mathcal{N}(G)$. Consider the dual normal Euler totient:
$$ \hat{\varphi}_{\mathcal{N}}(G) = \sum_{H \in \mathcal{N} (G)}\mu_{\mathcal{N}}(1,H) |G:H| $$ Let $V_1, \dots, V_r$ be equivalent class representatives of the irreducible complex representations of $G$.

*Theorem*: $\hat{\varphi}_{\mathcal{N}}(G) = \sum_{V_i \text{ faithful}} \dim(V_i)^2$.
*Corollary:*  $G$ has a faithful irreducible complex representation iff $\hat{\varphi}_{\mathcal{N}}(G) \neq 0$.

---

*Proof of the theorem:*

Let the fixed-point subspace $V_i^H=\{v \in V_i \ | \ hv=v ,\ \forall h \in H  \}$

*[Claim 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1740091/84284)*: $|G:H| = \sum_i\dim(V_i) \dim(V_i^H)$
*Claim 2*: $H$ is a normal subgroup iff $\forall i \ V_i^H = \{0\}$ or $V_i$.
*Claim 3*: $V_i$ is not faithful iff there is an atom $H$ of $\mathcal{N}(G)$ such that $V_i^H = V_i$.

Consider the set $L=\{ \bigoplus_i V_i^H \  | \ H \in \mathcal{N}(G) \}$ whose lattice structure is the reverse of $\mathcal{N}(G)$.
By applying the Crosscut Theorem and the inclusion-exclusion principle, together with the claims above, the result follows. $\square$

*Reference request*: does this theorem exist in the literature?

Comment: Re "does this theorem exist in the literature?": In Pálfy's paper on p. 97, a chain of equalities is displayed, and from the 1st and the 3rd line, on can extract the equality $$ \sum_{ \substack{ \phi \in \operatorname{Irr}(G) \\ \operatorname{Ker} \phi = 1 } } ( \deg \phi )^2 = \sum_{ N \vartriangleleft G } \mu(N) | G/N|. $$

Comment: @FriederLadisch: you are right, thanks!

Comment: @FriederLadisch: do you understand in what sense the (complicated) formula of Pálfy's paper is more interesting than this (easy) formula extracted above?

Comment: I think the point is that Palfy's formula depends only on the minimal normal subgroups of $G$ (together with the action of $G$ on the abelian ones), while the "easy" formula depends on *all* normal subgroups.